# How to configure Apache Camel, Kafka in docker-compose

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-camel, spring-camel

I need to create a service consuming from a Kafka topic, doing some validation/transformation and producing to a different Kafka topic using Camel route and Docker-compose

but I'm getting the following error, what am I doing wrong?

`INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.`

`WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.`

`WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected`

This is what I've wrote so far:

**application.properties**

```
camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true
server.port=8080
camel.component.kafka.brokers=localhost:9092


kafka.input-topic=inputTopic
kafka.output-topic=outputTopic
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms512m -Xmx2000m"

COPY target/*.jar  /opt/kafka-processor.jar

ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar /opt/kafka-processor.jar
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "inputTopic:1:1,outputTopic:1:1"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

  spring-app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_GROUP_ID: my-consumer-group
      SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET: earliest
      SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_KEY_SERIALIZER: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_VALUE_SERIALIZER: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_KEY_DESERIALIZER: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_VALUE_DESERIALIZER: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_PROPERTIES_SPRING_JSON_TRUSTED_PACKAGES: '*'
      SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_PROPERTIES_SPRING_JSON_TRUSTED_PACKAGES: '*'
      SPRING_KAFKA_TEMPLATE_DEFAULT_TOPIC: outputTopic
      SPRING_KAFKA_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_CONSUMER_FACTORY: kafkaListenerContainerFactory
      SPRING_KAFKA_TEMPLATE_PRODUCER_ID: my-kafka-producer
```

**TestRouter.java**

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class TestRouter extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer:tick?period=1000") // Send the current time every second
                .setBody(simple("${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"))
                .to("kafka:outputTopic");
    }
}
```

This is the output of docker-compose ps

> NAME                                    COMMAND
> SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
>
> kafka-processor-kafka-1        "/etc/confluent/dock…"   kafka running
> 0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
>
> kafka-processor-spring-app-1   "/bin/sh -c 'exec ja…"   spring-app
> running             0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
>
> kafka-processor-zookeeper-1    "/etc/confluent/dock…"   zookeeper
> running    2888/tcp,
> 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 3888/tcp

Comment: Why `camel.component.kafka.brokers=localhost:9092`? Certainly you want to use `kafka:9092` there?